# Can MongoDB periodically fail requests without an error?

Tags: mongodb

I've had a multiple cases where MongoDB failed to properly run a command. First it happened with one of my Python scripts (it's never failed before with the same code). Something broke because the command failed to run properly. I got suspicious and ran it by hand in NoSQLBooster. I got a response with no error. It said `acknowledged: true`, `matchedCount: NaN`, and `modifiedCount: NaN`. I ran it again without changing the command and it worked. Is this something that can happen regularly with MongoDB? Do I need to build in logic to ensure my commands went through properly?

In case it's relevant, here's the command:
`db.users.updateMany({}, {"$set": {"f1.f2": 0}})`

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible that there is a server bug that caused a command to not be executed, or its outcome to not be reported correctly, it is far more likely that either:

1. You, or a library you are using, didn't check the execution result and filled in some placeholder values that you think came from the server.
2. You checked the execution result but didn't do it correctly. The driver is supposed to handle this for you, but you can review server command documentation for the way that that particular command signifies failure. There are quite a few ways that many commands can fail (write concern errors, write errors, etc.).

Updating zero documents is *not* an error nor is it a failure in the server (you could've had zero documents in the collection to begin with, or none matched the filter you provided).

Comment: It updated NaN, not 0. I saw NaN through NoSQLBooster, so if there's an issue there, it would be a bug with NoSQLBooster. I know for a fact that there were documents in the collection as well (which is why the command worked properly with a second run).